# Replica of a trading chart

Tags: trading, forex, tradingview-api

Can I integrate a chart same as https://smarttrader.com/charts/ in my website?

I need fully integrated chart as given in above URL. 
I need a chart with live data on it and can create alert if some signaling is been created. That alert notification should be send to all users registered in my website.Any idea what strategy should I begin with?

I have also used charting library of trading view https://in.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/, but they have provided library with dummy URL https://demo_feed.tradingview.com, or if I will be using trading view chart what would be the correct URL which will provide all currencies live data.

Or Is it the case that I have to pay for some broker to get the API?

I am totally confused what would be the right scenario to integrate trading chart on my website.

Comment: Well, have you considered the question that why would someone provide a free api that would them potentially cause users not to come their site anymore because they come to your site?

Comment: Can I get some some providers link here so that I can communicate with them and purchase their APIs?